# how to set a beahavor for all my buttons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

i stared to built an app and i want that all my buttons in my app will look the same.
i write code for one button and i want my other buttons look alike.
here is my button code:

```
    UIImage *butimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"];
    UIImage *butimage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1press.png"];
    UIImage *butpress = [butimage3 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:0];
    UIImage *butimage2 = [butimage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:0];
    [button1 setBackgroundImage:butimage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setBackgroundImage:butpress forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

how can i do it?
thanks

Comment: Can't you just create a helper function like `initButton: (UIButton*)` with the above code and call it on all your buttons?

Comment: I… think you'd be best served by an Objective-C tutorial if you can't make a helper function / method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(anAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

I'm assuming you've created only a button, and assigning it all the images.

If you create more buttons, the code for giving them an action is the above one.

For the `anAction:` part, create a `-(void)anAction:(id)sender` (i.e) in order to tell the button to run that specific action.

**EDIT**

Declare your buttons as `IBOutlets`, place them in your `viewController.xib` and link them.

Then declare their properties in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` (the code you wrote, basically).

Then if you want them to perform some actions, write some `-(IBAction)actionForButton:(id)sender` and just assign them to the buttons in IB.

Comment: but i already created more buttons i just want to assigned then the same behavior...

Comment: i did this code:  [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(anAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal]; anAction is the code i write already, and it is still not working.

Comment: You have to assign the action to the controlEvent UIControlEvenTouchUpInside.

Comment: but when i assign the action UIControlEvenTouchUpInside the button change only after i clicked on and not when the viewcontroller is load.

Comment: Well, what does a button do? Basically when you touch it, an action occurs. So, if you want something to load as soon as the viewController is being loaded, then use viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad to perform your action.

Comment: so if i want to set for all mt button the same background when the view is load i must write for every button the same code? (    [button2 setBackgroundImage:butimage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 for every button)? there is a better and shorter way to do that?

Comment: Why don't you declare some IBOutlet UIButtons and link them to your controller? So that you can set up their background and give them action with IBAction. I still don't get what you want to do though.
Try to write code in viewWillAppear to stylish the buttons.

Comment: i declare my buttons as IBOutlet UIButtons but how can i set up the same background for all the buttons?